# pasting things in separate columns using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am new to python, and am trying to write a code that will take the items in one column of a CSV, and paste it into 4 columns of another csv (this will eventually be a quiz, and I will eventually be scrambling them). So far I have been able to get the code to print out the items in my column that I want 4 times, but the items are only appearing in one column, when I want to have each item one time in 4 columns.

This is what I have:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('name.csv', 'rU'), dialect = 'excel')
for column in reader:
    print column[1]
    print column[1]
    print column[1]
    print column[1]
```

This is printing out the items in column 1 four times into a new csv like this:

```
name
name
name
name
```

... when I want it to look like:

```
name   name   name   name
```

(in 4 columns).

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In python, when you execute code like:

```
print "Something"
```

...there's a newline stuck at the end that causes what you're seeing.

Two ways that you can get around this:

(1) Put a comma at the end of the line with the `print` statement, like:

```
>>> def fn():
...    print "1", 
...    print "2", 
...    print "3",
...    print "4"
... 
>>> fn()
1 2 3 4
```

This will insert a space character instead of the newline.

(2) Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting), like:

```
>>> print "{0}    {0}    {0}    {0}".format("value")
value    value    value    value
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function automatically adds a newline character to the end of the text it receives. To override this you can do this:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('name.csv', 'rU'), dialect = 'excel')
for column in reader:
    print(column[1], end='\t')
    print(column[1], end='\t')
    print(column[1], end='\t')
    print(column[1], end='\t')
```

Or the more pythonic version:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('name.csv', 'rU'), dialect = 'excel')
print '\t'.join([column[1]]*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to print on one line, you can just do:

```
print column[1], column[1], column[1], column[1]
```

instead of 4 prints.

second, if you plan to write this to a CSV file, use the `csv.writer`.

```
reader = csv.reader(open('name.csv', 'r'), dialect = 'excel')
writer = csv.reader(open('output.csv', 'w'), dialect = 'excel')

for column in reader:
    writer.writerow( [ column[1] ] * 4 )
```

Comment: Beware of `column[1]*4`. If `column[1] = 'name'` it will print `'namenamenamename'`.

Comment: You're right, I meant that outside the list.  Fixed.